# in loopback model.json file how to give validations

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

In model.json file I try to give validation property to array as per document says but it doesn't work .. (I want validaions by validations prperty only)
How to give validations array ?..

also see i tried as per in screenshort but that didn't work[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfr6J.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new to Loopback but the current (v3) [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#validations) states:

> **Warning:** This is not yet implemented. You must currently validate in
>   code; see [Validating model data](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Validating-model-data.html).

For now you have to put your validation code in the model's JS file.

This is the example given in the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Validating-model-data.html#examples):

**common/models/user.js**

```
module.exports = function(user) {
  user.validatesPresenceOf('name', 'email');
  user.validatesLengthOf('password', {min: 5, message: {min: 'Password is too short'}});
  user.validatesInclusionOf('gender', {in: ['male', 'female']});
  user.validatesExclusionOf('domain', {in: ['www', 'billing', 'admin']});
  user.validatesNumericalityOf('age', {int: true});
  user.validatesUniquenessOf('email', {message: 'email is not unique'});
};
```

This is reminiscent of Angular's [Reactive form validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation).